# JAVA - Override

Tags: java, overriding

I am new to Java.
I am using Eclipse IDE. I am getting an error If @override is there and not if @override has been removed. Can anyone help me in this regard. Thanks

The method remove(K) of type HashDictionary must override a superclass. This is error i am getting.

```
public interface DictionaryInterface <K extends Comparable<K>, V>
{
    public void insert(K key, V value);
    public V getValue(K str);
    public void remove(K key);
    public K[] getKeys();   
}


public class HashDictionary <K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements DictionaryInterface <K,V>{ 
    Hashtable<K,V> h;
    Class<K> KeyType;
    HashDictionary(Class<K> KeyType) {
        h=new Hashtable<K, V>();
        this.KeyType=KeyType;
    }
    public K[] getKeys() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Set<K> s = h.keySet();
        K elements[]=(K[])Array.newInstance(KeyType, h.size());
        int i=0;
        for(K e:s)
        {
            elements[i]=e;
            i++;
        }
        return elements;
}

    @Override
    public void remove(K key) {
        h.remove(key);
    }
    @Override
    public V getValue(K str) {
        return h.get(str);
    }
    @Override
    public void insert(K key, V value) {
        h.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exact error message ?

Comment: What in your opinion is the use of @Override annotation?

Comment: Show us your `DictionaryInterface`

Comment: So it goes like the answer with the most downvotes, and thus which got eventually deleted was the correct one. That is why you should always give us complete information, and don't keep us guessing.

Comment: I don't see how you don't get any error when `@Override` is removed. You have to override all the method interface, or declare the class as `abstract`.

Comment: All the three methods are getting over there. I don't know why. If I remove @override, the errors will be removed.

Comment: @user2454830 As Rohit said, still you need to ovveride `getKeys()`

Comment: @user2454830 override all the methods in your class or make class abstract as others has suggested

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that your interface `DictionaryInterface` dont have a method   `remove`  in it or with a different signature.

if you remove the annotation  `@Override`  then it consider as a local method.

Show `DictionaryInterface` or cross check it.

**Update:**

You might strike with some typo in your `IDE`. After ovverided all methods,

```
public class HashDictionary <K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements DictionaryInterface <K,V>{ 
        Hashtable<K,V> h;
        Class<K> KeyType;
        HashDictionary(Class<K> KeyType) {
            h=new Hashtable<K, V>();
            this.KeyType=KeyType;
        }

          @Override
            public void remove(K key) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                h.remove(key);
            }

        @Override
        public void insert(K key, V value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public V getValue(K str) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public K[] getKeys() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if your DictionaryInterface is a kind of Hashtable or HashMap, its `remove` can assume `Object` as a parameter, not `K`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only annotate methods that are in your interface. It seems your `DictionaryInterface` hasn't a method called `public void remove(K key)`

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works perfect. Nothing wrong with it. I tested it at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/TDtr5X).
No compilation errors online. I added `abstract` in order to be able to compile without having to implement the three other methods.

```
interface DictionaryInterface <K extends Comparable<K>, V>
{
    public void insert(K key, V value);
    public V getValue(K str);
    public void remove(K key);
    public K[] getKeys();   
}


abstract class HashDictionary <K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements DictionaryInterface <K,V>{ 
    Hashtable<K,V> h;
    Class<K> KeyType;
    HashDictionary(Class<K> KeyType) {
        h=new Hashtable<K, V>();
        this.KeyType=KeyType;
    }



    @Override
    public void remove(K key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        h.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: He didn't posted the abstract class.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The override annotation is still there. If the annotation was invalid, it wouldn't compile either.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine, even when I tried without abstract. One thing I am concerned that when you refer your method remove, it is properly referred to same or hashtable's remove method is being referenced. Please check. abstract is only need to show that all the methods are not implemented so compilations fails only due to that, but when all methods are overridden and @Override is removed it works fine. Note: I am also using Eclispe as IDE